# Will the load average of my Linux box increase if it reaches file descriptors or TCP connections limit?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp, load-average

Will the load average of my Linux box increase if it reaches file descriptors or TCP connections limit ?

Answer (score 2):

Once a Linux machine reaches the file descriptor limit, the load won't raise, but the machine will be unable to write anything else on disk and will practically stop working.

Similarly, reaching TCP connections limit means that the machine won't be able to accept new connections, but this won't have any impact on load.